# A class design of animal food choice question

Tags: c++

```
class Animal
{

};

class Herbivore:Animal
{
   void eat();
};

class Carnivore:Animal
{  
   void eat();
};

class Food
{
   bool bMeat;
   bool bVegeable;
};
```

I start out this class and all of a sudden I don't know what to do to with the class Food, as I would like to print out the correct food type each "kind" of animal favors most.

Sorry my food class size is small but I can't delete it as my whole program requires it to distinguish the food type. I will not mind if you suggest a different solution.

Comment: We're going to need more details. If you don't know what to do with your classes then that's a problem, but without the problem specification then we have even _less_ of an idea: we are not psychic!

Comment: We don't even know what this has to do with trees.

Comment: I reedit the title, and would like to know what else you want to know ?

Comment: animal should inherit from creature... should fix it

Comment: Where in your design is the connection between the food type and the animal type?

Comment: That's the problem I am stuck at.

Comment: The quesion really needs a litle more detail, as to how these classes must relate.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I'm not going to post a code snippet, I'll just try to explain (and by trees, I assume you mean inheritance).

I see that you've fixed the animals not inheriting from `Animal` which is good. However, to incorporate `Food` into the mix, you probably want to have a member of `Animal` (so every subclass of `Animal` has to have it) that is a `Food` called `favouriteFood` or something similar, which is initialized in the constructor of each subclass of `Animal` to that animal's favourite food.

The second thing I think you'll want to do is to make the member function `eat` both `virtual` and part of `Animal` so that each subclass of `Animal` has that member (and virtual so that when you call the function through an `Animal*` or `&`, it will call the correct version). Then make `eat` have one parameter which is a `Food`, the food they are eating.

Comment: @Real Oh, thought I saw the homework tag (in fact it was there but edited away). Would you like a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `bool eat(Food & food)`. In `eat` you can then check if your animal likes it and either return `false` or consume the food and return `true`. It might also make sense to throw a `bad_food` exception instead of the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would try:

```
class Food;
class Vegetable : Food { ; };
class Meat : Food { ; }

struct Animal
{
    virtual void eat(const Food& f)
    {;} // Stubbed.
};

struct Herbivore : Animal
{
    virtual void eat(const Vegetable&) = 0;
};

struct Carnivore : Animal
{
    virtual void eat(const Meat&) = 0;
};

struct Omnivore : Animal
{
    void eat(const Food& f)
    { cout << "I'm not picky.\n"; }
};
```

I suggest you look up concepts such as *double dispatch* and *Visitor Design Pattern*.